# How to display a flag based on condition in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

How do I display a green flag when material availability is marked as success but display a red flag when not?

```
IMAGE( 
CASE(  Material_availability__c , 
"Success", "/img/samples/flag_green.gif",
  NOT("Success"), "/img/samples/flag_red.gif", 
"/s.gif"), 
"priority flag")
```

Comment: Can you open /img/samples/flag_green.gif in your web browser to confirm that the file is accessible?

Comment: Yes it is accessible. When it is success it is displaying green but i dont know how to make else part for red flag.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have an account with no namespace, and you have a zip file in Static Resources called StatusImages with two files, passed.png and failed.png, you can use them like this in a formula field to display the image instead of text.

```
CASE( Material_availability__c ,
"Success",IMAGE( '/resource/StatusImages/passed.png' , "OK"),  
IMAGE( '/resource/StatusImages/failed.png' , "ERROR"))        //Default image
```

Comment: I need to display it as flag only.

Comment: What do you mean? You have images there, flag_green.gif, flag_red.gif.  Replace my example URL with the ones you confirmed work.

Comment: I found out. Following is the working code. IF( CONTAINS( UPPER(Material_availability__c ) , 'SUCCESS') , IMAGE( "/img/samples/flag_green.gif", "1x1 pixel green image"), IMAGE( "/img/samples/flag_red.gif", "1x1 pixel red image"))

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming Material_availability__c is a picklist?

IF( ISPICKVAL(Material_availability__c, 'Success') , 
   IMAGE(/img/samples/flag_green.gif, 'Success')  , 
   IMAGE(/img/samples/flag_red.gif, 'Failure'))